# Can't initialize static member in Singleton class in Java - Android

Tags: java, android, singleton

I've Singleton `SharedPreferences` helper class name `SyncPrefs`.

```
public class SyncPrefs {

    public static final String TAG = SyncPrefs.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String HrEmployeeSyncFinished = "hrEmployeeSyncFinished";

    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private SyncFinishedListener mSyncFinishedListener;

    private static SyncPrefs sSyncPrefs;

    private SyncPrefs(Context context, final Employees employees) {
        mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mSyncFinishedListener = new SyncFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSyncFinished() {
                employees.mSyncFinishedListener.onSyncFinished();
            }
        };
        // This call start sync & make isSyncFinished() getting called
        SyncUtils.get(context).requestSync(HrEmployee.AUTHORITY);
    }

    public static SyncPrefs getInstance(Context context, final Employees employees) {
        if (sSyncPrefs == null) {
            sSyncPrefs = new SyncPrefs(context, employees);
            Log.e(TAG, "getInstance(Context, Employees) called");
            Log.e(TAG, "sSyncPrefs initialized at: " + sSyncPrefs);
        }
        return sSyncPrefs;
    }

    public static SyncPrefs getInstance() {
        Log.e(TAG, "getInstance() called");
        Log.e(TAG, "sSyncPrefs is: " + sSyncPrefs);
        return sSyncPrefs;
    }

    private boolean isSyncFinished() {
        boolean isSyncFinished = isHrEmployeeSyncFinished();
        // isSyncFinished = true;
        Log.e(TAG, "isSyncFinished is :" + isSyncFinished);
        if (isSyncFinished) {
            try {
                setHrEmployeeSyncFinished(false);
                mSyncFinishedListener.onSyncFinished();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return isSyncFinished;
    }

    private boolean isHrEmployeeSyncFinished() {
        return mPrefs.getBoolean(HrEmployeeSyncFinished, false);
    }

    public SyncPrefs setHrEmployeeSyncFinished(boolean hrEmployeeSyncFinished) {
        mPrefs.edit().putBoolean(HrEmployeeSyncFinished, hrEmployeeSyncFinished).apply();
        if (hrEmployeeSyncFinished) {
            isSyncFinished();
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

The above code should run fine. but, somehow I can't initialize the `static` member `sSyncPrefs`. I've coonfirmed that `sSyncPrefs` is getting initialized. but, when I called `getInstance()` it always returns `null`.

Here's are some logs:

```
E/SyncPrefs: getInstance(Context, Employees) called
// Look here, it has memory address
E/SyncPrefs: sSyncPrefs initialized at: com.odoo.addons.employees.utils.SyncPrefs@7d0e0a5
E/HrEmployee: onSyncStarted
E/HrEmployee: onSyncFinished
E/SyncPrefs: getInstance() called
// now, where the memory address gone?
E/SyncPrefs: sSyncPrefs is: null
```

I don't know why this is happening. Any ideas, answers or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You can not use a non static variable in a static method

Comment: @Jens I didn't understand what you are saying. can you please tell me in detail

Comment: Are you using multiple threads?

Comment: It's Android. so, yes It might be possible. @khelwood so, what I've to do.

Comment: Try putting `sync` blocks around your access to the `sSyncPrefs` static field.

Comment: I'm using Java 7. is `sync` blocks available for me to use?

Comment: Singletons are something that you should avoid; especially lazily-initialized singletons with constructor parameters (e.g. what if you try to get an instance with different parameters?). Is there a good reason you can't just create a `SyncPrefs` instance somewhere and inject it wherever it is needed?

Comment: @AndyTurner I've already tried it. that din't work for me.

Comment: @Ka7Im1011 You may have tried *something* that didn't work (whatever "didn't work" means). I can assure you that you can write it without a singleton.

Answer (score 3):

I *strongly* recommend that you stop using a singleton here. As your question demonstrates, singletons are not easy to implement correctly, especially if you are initializing them lazily.

However, I believe that the reason your code isn't working here is facing a basic memory visibility issue: there is no guarantee that multiple threads see the most recent value for non-volatile variables.

(I am assuming that you don't simply have another bit of code that you didn't share, where you make another assignment of `sSyncPrefs` to `null`).

To implement this "correctly" (and I use the term loosely, because I don't think that a singleton is appropriate), you would need to use [double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking):

1. Make the `sSyncPrefs` variable `volatile`:

   ```
   private static volatile SyncPrefs sSyncPrefs;
   ```

   This ensures that updates to `sSyncPrefs` are not cached by threads, and that the value is always read from main memory.
2. Use synchronization when you check for nullity:

   ```
   public static SyncPrefs getInstance(Context context, final Employees employees) {
     if (sSyncPrefs == null) {
       synchronized (SyncPrefs.class) {
         if (sSyncPrefs == null) {
           sSyncPrefs = new SyncPrefs(context, employees);
           Log.e(TAG, "getInstance(Context, Employees) called");
           Log.e(TAG, "sSyncPrefs initialized at: " + sSyncPrefs);
         }
       }
     }
     return sSyncPrefs;
   }
   ```

   The first `null` check allows you to skip the synchronization once the variable has been initialized; if it is found to be null, the synchronization ensures that no other thread updates the value at the same time.
3. You also need to use double-checked locking in the no-args `getInstance()` method to add a check that the variable has actually been initialized.

   ```
   public static SyncPrefs getInstance() {
     if (sSyncPrefs == null) {
       synchronized (SyncPrefs.class) {
         if (sSyncPrefs == null) {
           throw new IllegalStateException("getInstance(Context, Employees) was not called first!");
         }
       }
     }
     return sSyncPrefs;
   }
   ```

Comment: Dohble-checked, seriously? :-)

Comment: Dohble-checked, seriously? :-)

Comment: @AlexanderKulyakhtin What alternative method do you propose (other than not using a lazy singleton)? Single-element enum doesn't work because of the parameters; always-synchronized works but is slower because it always locks.

Comment: @AlexanderKulyakhtin (And is your second comment just in case the first one was null?)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `getInstance()` and one of them will always return `null` unless you call the other one before.

Comment: This is true, but the posted logcat shows that the one which actually does initialize the variable is called first.

Comment: Maybe the singleton gets garbage collected

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, You're right. I've initialized it.

Comment: Maybe you initialized it but it's gone. Why not to do the same lazy initialization in getInstance() as you did in getInstance(x, y)

Comment: @AlexanderKulyakhtin That's not possible because the second param is `Fragment` itself. I can't call `getInstace(x,y)` from anywhere unless from `Fragment` itself.

Comment: @AlexanderKulyakhtin I guarantee that `sSyncPrefs` will initialized first. before any no-params `getInstance()` get called.

Answer (score -2):

You need to set the Static in the constructor so when the singleton is initialised then it sets the TAG, 
The code you list doesn't have the method you are calling either. SyncPrefs is a singleton so there should be no public constructor and the constructor should either be checked on the getInstance or within a static block (the Spring way of doing it)

```
    public static class SyncPrefs {

     private static SyncPrefs instance;
     private static final String TAG;

     private SyncPrefs() {
         TAG = "Something";
    }

     public static SyncPrefs getInstance() {
        if(instance == null)
        { 
             instance = new SyncPrefs();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so 2 negative entries, but where are the comments explaining why? This is not how it is done.